# JPA EclipseLink table creation order

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a working project that uses JPA to persist data on MySQL (EclipseLink as provider). Recently I wanted to drop the database and create it again with the tables via Eclipse => EclipseLink 'Generate tables from entities'. I also have the persistence.xml updated (first generated automatically, then modified manually to narrow down on this problem).

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>xxx.entity.options.Difficulty</class>
<class>xxx.entity.options.Options</class>
```

(Omitted the rest since it is ok otherwise => it is working in general)

The problem is that when I generate the tables I get the error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'xxx.DIFFICULTY' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
```

(The entity classes have table names defined:
@Entity
@Table(name = "DIFFICULTY"))

If I comment out the 'Options' from persistence.xml, the 'DIFFICULTY' table gets created ok. Then uncommenting 'Options' again and re-generating the tables => the 'OPTIONS' table will be created also (Options has @ManyToOne association with the Difficulty).

In the persistence.xml I have

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
```

as I am still developing.

In the Options class I have

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Difficulty difficulty = null;
```

(Many Options are suppose to have the same Difficulty selected, so none really owns one. I hope this is correct?)

After The Difficulty and Options tables were created successfully, I was able to re-create the rest of the database tables.

1. The question is that should I (be able to) specify the order in which the tables are created?
2. Have I something wrong with the @ManyToOne association?

Already spent couple of hours on this issue, but couldn't figure it out what is the problem.

Sorry for the long text, I just try to explain the whole situation.
Last time I received 'tl; dr;' answer (didn't know by that time what it meant), I spent 6 hours looking the wrong thing, so please do not bother to answer in such case.

Comment: Can you post the full error and stack?  What is the problem with the create statement?

Comment: Here's the full stack trace. http://pastebin.com/Biz16Ux3 . Sorry for the delay. Couldn't get it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the exceptions stack, you'll see it is coming from your entity's default constructor.  This constructor is trying to issue a query by obtaining an entitymanager, and is failing because the table it needs doesn't exist yet.  When you create that one table, the constructor can query it, which allows everything to proceed.

You should not have business logic in your default constructor.  This is used by the provider, and is getting called during deployment before DDL.  Removing that will resolve the issue.

Comment: That explains. I tried to make it generate the tables automatically earlier (didn't succeed at the time). Thought I had this removed and couldn't figure this out from the errors (obviously something was left).

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the class/schema in between your last create?  It could be that you have added or removed new relationships, so EclipseLink is not able to drop the old constraints.

For drop-and-create-tables EclipseLink will basically do the following,

- drop known constraints
- drop known tables
- create known tables
- create known constraints

In the latest release EclipseLink will try a couple drop passes to try and handle unknown constraints, but the best method for a rapidly changing development schema would be to drop the entire schema in between deployments.

Comment: The problem with constraints sounds plausible, but the thing is that I dropped the whole database before creating completely new (create empty db + user). I wanted to see that the db can be created from a scratch when it doesn't exist yet (the situation what is going to be when this game is run for the first time). I'd expect the creation work in such case easily, but got this error instead (and there is only 2 tables to be created as everything else was commented out)

Comment: I have to check if the 'drop database' is sufficient at all. Maybe I need to drop the schema separately if is not done with the 'drop db'?

Comment: Well, it was tested fast. After 'drop database xxx', i ran 'drop schema xxx' and got:
ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'xxx'; database doesn't exist

Comment: After I create the 'DIFFICULTY' table, I will be able to create all the other tables at once.